# Display Value for related_records field

Tags: c#, .net, servicenow

In `dmn_demand` [Demand Management] table, what is the `Display Value` for `realted_records` field.

For example,

For `assigned_to` field, the display value is `Name`. Similarly, I want the `Display Value` for the `realted_records` field.

Answer (score 1):

The display value is actually determined by the table which that field references (assuming it's a reference field).

So for example, if you go to the field that the assigned_to field references (probably sys_user) and look at the table dictionary (right click -> configure -> table), you'll see the list of fields, and on one of them, "display=true" should be true.

Here's some [more information](http://wiki.servicenow.com/?title=Reference_Fields#Selecting_the_Display_Value&gsc.tab=0).

Note that you can generally only have one "display" field on a given table.